# Trying to get more space removed from my header

Tags: title, headers, customization

The last time , you help me to remove the header from all the pages besides the Home page (thanks again by the way). 
The reason for me to do so , is because I don' t want my music player for example to be too below , having people to need to scroll down.

I am still looking for more space , and get rid off the title for example, or make it smaller . And know that I added a follow button of Twitter , the top takes more space , and the music player is more below .

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Could you please post an example of the code or page(s) that you are having trouble with?

Comment: it s a twentyeleven theme . do you want me to copy the whole header.php?              here is the page   http://www.danielbelseamusic.com/music-player/      the player is too low . i am looking to get rid of some space at the top             . i changed with your help from          if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
to       if ( ! empty( $header_image ) && is_front_page() ) :     which take off the image of the header of all the pages , but i still want more space , like the title to be removed ( from the pages but not from the home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your music player looks okay to me. On line 1090 of your style.css file, you have the top padding of class `.singular.page .hentry` set to `3.5em`. Start there. You might also want to remove padding and/or margins from the elements above the player, such as the navigation. If you want to remove the title, add `if ( ! is_front_page() ) :` before your call to `the_title()`.

Comment: thanks Joseph . please , can you tell me exactly what to do ,like:go to this php page,  ...on a line it says    this and that   ,  add this and this . i am not too good in that

Comment: i see the singular stuffs ( i think ) on style.css , but i don t know what to change . all together i don t know how it works the codes . are there some rules ....

Comment: wonderful Joseph . i managed to do some stuff with ur help.thanx a lot. i am so happy to have found this forum :)

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, the conditional goes in single.php IIRC. I'm glad I could help you! Happy Holidays!